# How to structure a For loop with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a csv file containing the below data

```
TSE/5216,"Kuramoto Co., Ltd. (5216)"
TSE/7235,"Tokyo Radiator Mfg. Co., Ltd. (7235)"
TSE/8016,"Onward Holdings Co., Ltd. (8016)"
```

I read it into a pandas dataframe

```
# The csv file that was downloaded doesnt come with headers, so I wrote it in using `names`
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=False, header=None, 
                     names=['Codes', 'Company Name'])
```

I am writing a `for` loop to download data from Quandl and saving it into a `SQL.db` file. I have the below code

```
for each_code in df['Codes']:
    get_prices = Quandl.get(each_code, returns='pandas')
    # Data to SQL
    get_prices.to_sql(name=each_code, con=engine')
```

**My problem** is that I want the name of the sql table to be the `Company Name` as shown in `file.csv`, instead of `each_code`. How should I structure my codes to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`df.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate over the rows:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    get_prices = Quandl.get(row['Codes'], returns='pandas')
    # Data to SQL
    get_prices.to_sql(name=row['Company Name'], con=engine)
```

or [use zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/190597) to pair `df['Codes']` with `df['Company Name']`:

```
for code, name in zip(df['Codes'], df['Company Name']):
    get_prices = Quandl.get(code, returns='pandas')
    # Data to SQL
    get_prices.to_sql(name=name, con=engine)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. Thumbs up for `zip` :)